# Buy token just after the pair deployment?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Hello i saw this today :

[image]

I'm wondering if how it's possible for someone to buy a token in same time as pair deployment.
If i check into some mempool we do not have the info that a pending order is a creation of new pair, so how it's possible ?

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If the deployment transaction is in the public mempool, you can analyse the `to` and `data` parameters to check what it's about, or even simulate the transaction and check the events it generates.

So, generally a deployment tx will have `to` equal to some UniV2/3 factory address or equivalent. Then, knowing the ABI of the contract, you can extract the parameters from `data` and find the two tokens and initial amounts.